# chrome extension create window: alwaysOnTop

Tags: google-chrome-extension, window

According to that API definition: 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#type-Window
window has a (new) property called 'alwaysOnTop' (As I understand, it means that even if the user clicked somewhere else on the screen, this window sticks to the front, like 'chat for google' does).

I can't get how to create a window which has this property (chrome.window.create() doesn't contain it among the parameters it gets). I've tried several ways, like using the function that create gets and other options, but none worked. The console messages didn't help me to figure out what the right way is.

Could someone please post a short example that demonstrate a creation of such a window ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`alwaysOnTop` is not a valid argument for `chrome.windows.create`.

Indeed, it is mentioned in the documentation, but listened under the [`Window` type](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#type-Window), which describes an object which is passed to many of the `chrome.windows` API method callbacks.

Compare [`chrome.windows.create#createData`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#property-create-createData) and the [`Window` type's properties](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#Window-properties).

Comment: Thanks Rob. I've noticed that, but the Window object is mentioned [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#property-create-createData) as an optional parameter to the callback passed to create: "callback ( optional function )
Parameters
window ( optional Window )
**Contains details about the created window**." So I thought this is the  say to obtain this property to the created window. Anyhow, is there no way for obtaining this ?

Comment: @Rapher No. What you're quoting is the "read-only" information received by the callback of `chrome.windows.create`. You cannot set this property yourself (yet).

Comment: So, why does this property exist at all, if there is no way to actually set it to a window ?

Comment: @Rapher Use `type: "panel"` when you create the window using `chrome.windows.create`. This will create a window which is always on top *provided that* panels are enabled, via `chrome://flags/` or using the `--enable-panels` flag.

Comment: Thank you. Before I've posted this question, I searched a lot to find where this flag (--enable-panels) hides itself :). I can't find it, would you mind to point me to the right place ?

Comment: @Rapher Visit `chrome://flags/` and search for "Enable Panels" **OR** change your Chrome shortcut and append the flag, eg `chrome.exe --enable-panels`. The first option is the easiest (and persistent) option, the second one only works if you launch Chrome using that shortcut.

Comment: So both are not ideal if I intend my extension to be used by other people. Too bad :( Oh, one day panels will be available without those flags, yay! :) @Rob, Many thanks. +1 for the back and forth conversation.

Comment: This option _is_ available for **Chrome Apps** (`chrome.app.window.create`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960076/chrome-packaged-app-alway-on-top-window for more details.