# Chrome Packaged app, Always on top window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, always-on-top, google-chrome-app

i am writing a text editor, i need the app window be always on top when switching to browser or e-book reader software. as i know ,for windows users, chrome doesn't provide any solution. is there any parameter to send when creating window to make window always on top?

or can i provide any button in app to turn this feature on or off?

Code i use to create window in bg.js:

```
var launch = function () {
chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
  type: 'shell',
  width: 440,
  height: 680,
  minWidth: 440,
  maxHeight: 680,
  id: 'paat-start'
});
};
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(launch);
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(launch);
```

thank for any suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

As Ben Wells mentioned above, this feature *is* now available in the stable release (either v33 or v34) via the `alwaysOnTop` option in `chrome.app.windows.create`. Note that special permissions are required in the `manifest.json` file. Example:

**background.js**

```js
chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
  alwaysOnTop: true,
}, function (appWindow) {
  // Window created and will remain on top of others.

  // Change the property programmatically via:
  //appWindow.setAlwaysOnTop();
});
```

**manifest.json**

```js
"permissions": [
  "alwaysOnTopWindows"
]
```

This seems to have been added in [issue 26427002](https://codereview.chromium.org/26427002), gone stable in [issue 159523002](https://codereview.chromium.org/159523002) and [issue 48113024](https://codereview.chromium.org/48113024) thanks to [the community](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/apps-dev/Lxm_uFTUMZA)!

---

I had looked into this a while back and wanted to catalog my findings since historically there were some discrepancies in the documentation [which previously stated](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#property-CreateWindowOptions-alwaysOnTop) the name of the required permission was `alwaysOnTop`, but using this caused a **"permission is unknown"** error.

Reading through the [original proposal for this feature](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F54IJ4nDQGU8hWwOOcYopyXXQirBFPjvZih4zOyfKgY/edit) lead me to [issue 326361](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=326361) which mentions the permission setting is actually called `alwaysOnTopWindows`. Using this one back then, however, yielded a **"requires Google Chrome dev channel or newer"** error (probably since the feature wasn't yet stable).

I *did* find it peculiar from [browsing the source code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/permissions/chrome_api_permissions.cc&q=alwaysOnTopWindows&sq=package:chromium&l=396), these two permissions might be aliases of each other, but that might be because I don't fully understand the Chromium codebase.

Comment: The documentation you've linked at "documentation which used to say" is quite big. Can you use a more specific anchor (`#...`)? You can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/display-anchors/poahndpaaanbpbeafbkploiobpiiieko to find the anchor.

Comment: Done. I updated my link to https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#property-CreateWindowOptions-alwaysOnTop. You'll notice that the documentation now has the correct value, though. Not sure if there's a way to view the history of the docs :-)

Comment: The documentation is generated from https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/ (static files, server code) and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/ (JSON files). Just click on the relevant file, click on "View in" (upper-right corner of viewer), then "Subversion Revision Log" to see the file's history.

Comment: And I strongly suggest to link to the viewvc page instead of codesearch if you're talking about a specific piece of code. Due to refactoring, the part of the answer that refers to a specific bit of code could become confusing in the future when the source code changes.

Answer (score 4):

`chrome.app.window.create` does support a boolean [`alwaysOnTop`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#property-options-alwaysOnTop) option in more recent versions of Chrome. The feature is currently in beta channel on most platforms and at least dev channel on the rest.

Comment: This should become available for general use in M33. We're still ironing out some issues in M32.