# Chrome Apps development

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am new in Chrome app development, so please sorry if my question is stupid :)
I need to made my app window to be 'always on top', I've revived [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html)

but it is not clear for me how should I call setAlwaysOnTop().

My background.js looks like this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'bounds': {
    'width': 400,
    'height': 500
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can only have this behavior in the dev channel but it will soon be released for the stable channel. When it is added, you can have the "alwaysOnTopWindows" and "app.window" permission in your manifest.json and in your background.js have this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'bounds': {
       'width': 400,
       'height': 500
   },
   'alwaysOnTop': true
});
```

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this works on 34.0.1809.0 dev.

Comment: If all goes well this will be available in stable in 34.

Comment: Yep, now available in stable! Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960076/chrome-packaged-app-alway-on-top-window/25121672#answer-25121672